# Which language code set (WALS, Linguasphere, ISO 639‑3 or Glottolog) should be the basis for a comparative linguistic project?

Tags: list-of-languages, comparative-linguistics, standards

To compile a word-list database which includes the available scattered word lists (mainly Swadesh lists), which language code should one use?

- [WALS](http://wals.info/languoid) with 2679 entries, lots of linguistic data included. (Maintained Max Planck Institute)
- [Glottolog](http://glottolog.org/glottolog/language) with 7943 entries and also lots of data included. (Maintained Max Planck Institute)
- [Linguasphere](http://www.linguasphere.info/lcontao/fichier-pdf.html) with about 21000 entries and some info included from 2000 or 2011. Theoretically limit of 18.9 million entries, thus theoretically flexible to include dialects and historic languages. (as far as I can tell dormant, otherwise Linguasphere Observatory)
- [ISO 639-3](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/language_codes.htm) [see also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-3_codes) with currently about 7865 entries (theoretical limit of 17576 entries), used by several other sources. (Maintained by [SIL](http://www-01.sil.org/iso639-3/default.asp))
- a different language code set all together?

I realise this is a bit of a subjective question but does anyone feel confident enough to say "*this language code set should be used for the following reasons*"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can afford the extra work, use as many of the lists as possible, of course using explicit tags declaring from which set the code is taken, e.g.,

```
<languagecode type="iso639-3">eng</languagecode>
```

If you want to use only one of them, use ISO 639-3 if possible. It is an International Standard, well-maintained, frequently used and easily accessible. It is well received in the community and used, e.g. by [OLAC: Open Language Archives Community](http://www.language-archives.org/) and by the [CLARIN Project](https://www.clarin.eu/sites/default/files/Standards%20for%20LRT-v6.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will see how much effort it is to combine them.